# Tag synonym - death & death-afterlife

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I was attempting to helpfully consolidate the tags "death" and "death-afterlife" and proposed the synonym in the wrong direction--not so helpful of me huh? My bad for the rookie mistake.

The stack exchange post I read on the matter suggested raising a question on meta.

How do I undo the tag synonym proposal and re-propose in the opposite direction? (death is a synonym, death-afterlife is the target).

Comment: Mods can easily switch the direction of tag synonyms. Though in this case I don't really think the two should be synonyms, they concern pretty different topics.

Comment: I've cleaned up the death-afterlife tag as it doesn't seem useful. Questions can be tagged death, afterlife, or both, as appropriate.

Comment: @curiousdannii thanks for fixing that

Comment: Also, thank you for all your tag wikis. They have all been well written and appropriately neutral for a site like this!